# When I open second collapse the state is getting the same data. I need to get the data on when the collapse is triggered

Tags: reactjs

You can see the sample code here.
https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-germain-rci4d?file=/app.js

I know my issues are on handling state by maybe you can gave me some idea on how I can do that thanks =) for the help in future

```
  collapseOnTrigger = id => {
    const newSubData = [
      {
        id: "tests",
        subId: "sub test",
        subData: "sssss ssss"
      },
      {
        id: "ss",
        subId: "1",
        subData: "1"
      }
    ].find(item => item.id === id);
    this.setState({ subDatas: [newSubData] });
  };
```

```
        {this.state.list.map((data, index) => (
          // Only do this if items have no stable IDs
          <Collapse onChange={() => this.collapseOnTrigger(data.id)}>
            <Panel header={data.data} key={data.id}>
              {this.state.subDatas.map((data, index) => (
                <ul>
                  <li>{data.subData}</li>
                </ul>
              ))}
            </Panel>
          </Collapse>
        ))}
```

Here is the screenshot
[image]

Comment: your sandbox isn't doing what the screenshot says you are doing?

Comment: I'm sorry about that can you check again? thanks

Comment: your problem is you have way too many different pieces of state and stuff to track. try and just map over one array and allow the individual objects to contain all the data. you could include a key called `open: false` and then once you click on the the row you toggle that to `true | false`

Comment: okay thanks for the idea @RedBaron I'll try that one thanks

Comment: let me know if you need any more help with that

Answer (score 2):

> There's no need to manage `subData` in the state.
>   Just iterate over it, and find the desired value.

```
{
    this.state.list.map((data, index) => (
        // Only do this if items have no stable IDs
        <Collapse key={data.id} >
            <Panel header={data.data}>
                {
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            {
                                this.state.subDatas.find(item => item.id === data.id).subData
                            }
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                }
            </Panel>
        </Collapse>
    ))
}
```

Comment: I think there still an issue with your code I realize I need to  get the data only when you click the collapse.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is when you trigger `collapseOnTrigger`, you set `state.subDatas` to the subData of item `id`, so in the loop to render subDatas, it render the only item in `this.state.subDatas`.

You should filter the `subDatas` before render it, currently it render all elements of it.

```
{this.state.subDatas
    .filter(subData => subData.id === data.id)
    .map((subData, index) => (
      <ul key={subData.subId}>
        <li>{subData.subData}</li>
      </ul>
    ))
}
```